# ssh not working for all logins

Tags: ssh

I was doing a cleanup and by mistake i deleted some dir from /var which resulted in a situation that no other session /ssh is possible .
When I am trying from ILOM via vsp -- says `Error Service Module`
and when I took `ssh` in verbose mode --  I get following error .

Can you please suggest how to correct and make this system healthy.

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.253.224.7 [10.253.224.7] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '10.253.224.7' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
This system is restricted solely to <company> authorized users for legitimate business purposes only. The actual or attempted unauthorized access, use, or modification of this system is strictly prohibited by <company>. Unauthorized users are subject to Company disciplinary proceedings and/or criminal and civil penalties under state, federal, or other applicable domestic and foreign laws. The use of this system may be monitored and recorded for administrative and security reasons. Anyone accessing this system expressly consents to such monitoring and is advised that if monitoring reveals possible evidence of criminal activity, <company> may provide the evidence of such activity to law enforcement officials. All users must comply with <company> Security Policy & Requirements regarding the protection of <company> information assets.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
eric@10.253.224.7's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8

Warning! You have entered into a secured area!                               
Your IP, Login Time, Username has been noted for auditing purposes.          
This service is restricted to authorized users only.                         
All activities on this system are logged. Unauthorized access will be fully  
investigated and action would be taken appropriately.                        
LOG OFF IMMEDIATELY IF YOU ARE NOT AN AUTHORIZED USER                        
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to 10.253.224.7 closed.
Transferred: sent 1912, received 3680 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 19038.4, received 36642.9
debug1: Exit status 254
```

Comment: it looks very much like you get logged in; are you concerned about the motd banner, the kerberos errors, what?

Answer (score 1):

First, you're going to have to find a way to log into the server. If SSH won't let you because it can't log you in properly, that's not something you can somehow bypass, otherwise SSH would be insecure.

Once you have root access, there's a good chance that reinstalling the package containing the SSH server will recreate the necessary directories with the proper permissions, e.g. `yum reinstall openssh-server` or `apt-get --reinstall install openssh-server`. You may need to do this for other packages that have been disrupted as well.

If that doesn't do the trick, look for clues in log messages. If you aren't getting any logs, trace the SSH process, e.g.

```
ps -C sshd
strace -f -efile -p…
```

Figuring out what's missing and what the right permissions are takes some experience.

It would be more reliable to restore a backup, that way you know you haven't forgotten anything.

Comment: hi , thanks for response . i tried but getting this :

Comment: root@POOCC001 opt]#
[root@POOCC001 opt]# yum reinstall openssh-server
Setting up Reinstall Process
rhel                                                     | 2.9 kB     00:00 ...
Installed package openssh-server-5.3p1-94.el6.x86_64 (from patch) not available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@POOCC001 opt]#
[root@POOCC001 opt]#
[root@POOCC001 opt]#
[root@POOCC001 opt]# apt -get  --reinstall install openssh-server
bash: apt: command not found
[root@POOCC001 opt]# uname -a
Linux POOCC001 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Nov 10 22:19:54 EST 2013 x86_64
x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@POOCC001 opt]#

Comment: no space between "apt" and "get" -- `apt-get ...`

Comment: [root@POOCC001 cache]# apt-get --reinstall install openssh-server
bash: apt-get: command not found
[root@POOCC001 cache]#

Comment: @GULAB Use your distribution's package manager, of course. `yum` and `apt-get` were just examples, because you didn't say what distribution you're using.